# Replace a directive's scope element in a template with link based JavaScript function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my Angular directive code

```
.directive('articleItem', function($sce) {
  return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  scope: { wordtag:'='},
  replace: true,
  template: '<!--  -->'
  + '<article>'

  + '<!-- {{wordtag}} is replaced -->'
  + '<div>{{wordtag}}</div>'

  + '<!-- {{wordtag}} is not replaced -->'
  + '<a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playSound(\'{{wordtag}}-english\')">'

  + '</article>'
}
```

Here is the relevant subset of my HTML code (inc. inline Javascript)

```
<article:item ng-repeat="audio in event.audios" wordtag="audio"/>

<script>
function playSound(audiotag) {
    document.getElementById(audiotag).play();
}
</script>
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here, and how to overcome?
Thanks.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rHewUcDIxkzeBSfaO1Lq?p=preview

Comment: When you look at the rendered HTML, Is your element being rendered as you'd expect?  What are you seeing in the console?

Comment: <a xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playSound('{{wordtag}}-english')"></a>

Comment: similar issue as described at [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)